# Getting significance stars from a robust regression model using texreg

Tags: r, stargazer, texreg

`texreg`, by default at least, doesn't place significance stars on the coefficients from a robust linear model fitted using the `rlm` function from the `MASS` package. Is there any way to make it? `stargazer` does, actually, as the following MWE shows:

```
library('MASS','stargazer','texreg')

mod <- lm(speed ~ dist, cars)
modR <- rlm(speed ~ dist, cars)

stargazer(mod)
texreg(mod)

stargazer(modR)
texreg(modR)
```

P.S.: This likely has something to do with the authors of `MASS` apparently just not liking P-values, as they are conspicuously omitted from the `rlm` output altogether: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205614/p-values-and-significance-in-rlm-mass-package-r

And yet `stargazer` can make the stars just fine. Most people seem to think `texreg` is better, which is the main reason I ask.

P.P.S.: I thought I'd try using `lmRob` from the `robust` package instead, but there's an even sillier problem with that: `texreg` has a method for an object of signature `lmrob`, but not `lmRob`, which is what I'm outputting. I assume `robust` updated and changed this object name but `texreg` hasn't caught up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code for texreg and follow the "trail of `stars`" you eventually end up looking at a call to an undocumented `ciforce`-force function (`texreg:::ciforce`) whose `ci.force`-parameter is by default FALSE. Set that to TRUE:

```
 texreg(modR, ci.force=TRUE)

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c }
\hline
 & Model 1 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $8.21^{*}$      \\
            & $[6.46;\ 9.97]$ \\
dist        & $0.17^{*}$      \\
            & $[0.13;\ 0.20]$ \\
\hline
Num. obs.   & 50              \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^*$ 0 outside the confidence interval}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

... and watch the stars come out.

Do note that the standard errors in `summary(modR)` (from MASS) are stated to be used for the construction, not of p-values but rather of t-values.